# How to saveRDS to stdout?

Tags: r

I got the following error. Is there a way to saveRDS to stdout directly? Thanks.

```
R> saveRDS(1, stdout())
Error in saveRDS(1, stdout()) : 
  binary-mode connection required for ascii=FALSE
```

Comment: If you look at `stdout()`, it's `mode = w` and `text = text`; to write a binary those need to be `mode = wb` and `text = binary`. You can set `ascii = TRUE` in `saveRDS` as the error suggests if you want, but that somewhat defeats the purpose.

Comment: Is there a way to make stdout `mode = wb` and `text = binary`?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not short of diving into the C API. Why do you want to write a pile of binary to stdout?

Comment: If the data can be written to stdout, then I can use `|` in shell and avoid saving any temp files in the analysis flow.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422575/how-to-write-raw-type-bytes-to-stdout